# How to go to an activity when app is in background?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When my app is in foreground, it runs the following code accordingly:

```
mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if(intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)){
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);
                    displayFirebaseRegId();
                }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)){
                    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                            new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                    .setContentTitle("ABC")
                                    .setContentText(message);
                    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, SearchActivity.class);
                    resultIntent.putExtra("selectedTitle",message);
                    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
                    // your application to the Home screen.
                    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
                    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
                    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                                    0,
                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                            );
                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    mNotificationManager.notify(123, mBuilder.build());
```

Below is the code on handling notification:

```
private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        }else{
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }
```

When there is a notification and my app is in background, it does not run the first snippet code above and go to the activity as specified. It just opens the app which opens the MainActivity.

How can I make it goes to the Activity as specified even if my app is in background when there is a notification ?

Comment: Are you trying to make an activity *pop up* even when your app is in background?

Comment: Yes and go directly to the Activity which I have specified @AL.

Comment: In general, it is *bad UX* to make an app pop up without any user interaction. Just think of [pop-up ads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop-up_ad).

Comment: @AL. no i mean, when user clicks on the notification message, it goes to the activity as specified. It currently works when the app is in foreground but does not work when the app is in background.

Comment: Ow. Okay. I thought you wanted to make it pop up without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
   Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, SearchActivity.class);
   resultIntent.putExtra("selectedTitle",message);
**notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);**
```

You should add flag as "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP"
That creates new instance of an activity.

**UPDATE**

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = 
                 stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,resultIntent);
```

Comment: this works great. Another problem arises which is notification only shows when my app is in MainActivity and in background. There isn't any notification when app is in other activity. There's only notification sound.